# loop regression columns r

Tags: r, loops, logistic-regression

I have a dataframe like this one

```
ID  matching_var    status  code1   code2
 1  1                0       1      0
 2  1                1       1      0
 3  2                0       0      1
```

I have several other columns like code1 and code2, up to code25 and I would like to do these regressions:

```
fit1<-clogit(status~code1+strata(matching_variable),data=df)

fit2<-clogit(status~code2+strata(matching_variable),data=df)
```

…

```
fit25<-clogit(status~code25+strata(matching_variable),data=df
```

My variables code 1 to code25 are in columns 4 to 29 of my df

I would like to find a way to automate this without having to type in each regression model, and I would like to have all the regression results in one table

I have tried this:

```
regression <- function(x){code<- x[,4:29]
 f <- as.formula(
paste("status ~", code, "+ strata(matching_var)"))
 clogit(f, data = x)
 }

result_reg<-lapply(df,regression)


lapply(result_reg, summary)
```

But it doesn't work, several other posts deal with the same subject but I haven't managed to find a solution to my problem...

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You have omitted a closing double quote from your call to `paste` in your `regression` function.  Is that a typo in the question or a typo in your code?  And I think you may need `code <- 4:29` rather than `code <- x[, 4:29]`...

Comment: @Limey it was an error while copying the code, I changed 
I tried that too but it doesn't work either, i have this message :                                                             Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  incorrect model formula in ExtractVars
De plus : Warning message:
Using formula(x) is deprecated when x is a character vector of length > 1.
  Consider formula(paste(x, collapse = " ")) instead. 
Called from: terms.formula(formula, data = data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I used the `mtcars` dataset since you did not post your data.
Furthermore, explicitly call `library` when you use non-common function like `clogit`

```
 df <- mtcars
    library(survival)
    regression <- function(column){
      f <- as.formula(
      paste("vs ~", column, "+ strata(carb)"))
    survival::clogit(f, data = df)
    }
    
    result_reg<-lapply(colnames(df)[9:11],regression)
    lapply(result_reg, summary)
```